# How to restrict that case classes have specific parameter types constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala

Let's say I have case classes something like below.

```
trait Foo {
  def a: String
}

case class Bar(a: String,b: Option[Int]) extends Foo{
  def this(test: Test) = this(test.foo,None)
}

case class Buzz(a: String,b: Boolean) extends Foo{
  def this(test: Test) = this(test.foo,false)
}
```

I'm using the constructor `def this(test: Test)` via reflection and working as I expected.

A method signature that I use the constructor is something like this

```
def test[T <: Foo: ClassTag](cb: (String) => Future[T]): Future[Result]
```

What I want to do is restrict that any case classes that extends trait `Foo` needs to have `def this(test: Test)`.And the case if any of them don't have it, It should be a compile error.

My attempt

```
//Compile error
trait Foo[T] {
  def a: String
  def this(test: Test):T
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the type system to enforce that a class has a specific constructor. This shouldn't really be a surprise, because you're already using reflection to access said constructor. Using a reflective call, the only way to check for the appropriate constructor would be to use more reflection--preferably via a macro to mail compilation fail.

There is almost always a better way than using reflection, though. In this case, we can use a type class to find the correct method that can build a sub-type of `Foo` (or anything, really) from a `Test`.

Let's assume `Test` looks like this:

```
case class Test(foo: String)
```

Then, we define a `TestBuilder` type class, which can provide evidence that we can build an `A` from a `Test`.

```
trait TestBuilder[A] {
    def build(test: Test): A
}

// Convenience method for creating type class instances
object TestBuilder {
  def apply[A](f: Test => A): TestBuilder[A] = new TestBuilder[A] {
    def build(test: Test): A = f(test)
  }
}
```

Then, we define out `Foo`s, each with an instance of `TestBuilder[A]`, where `A` is the type of each `Foo`:

```
trait Foo {
  def a: String
}

case class Bar(a: String, b: Option[Int]) extends Foo

object Bar {
    implicit val builder = TestBuilder(test => Bar(test.foo, None))
}

case class Buzz(a: String, b: Boolean) extends Foo

object Buzz {
    implicit val builder = TestBuilder(test => Buzz(test.foo, false))
}
```

Note that we no longer need the alternate constructors, and rely on the type class instances to build our `Foo`s using `apply`.

Now, your `test` method *could* look something like this. I changed around the return types because you don't define any implementation or what `Result` is, but the idea is the same.

```
def test[T <: Foo : ClassTag : TestBuilder](cb: String => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  val test = Test("abc")
  // use the implicitly resolved type class to build `T` from a `Test`
  val t = implicitly[TestBuilder[T]].build(test) 
  Future(t).andThen {
    case Success(x) => cb(x.a)
  }
}
```

Now, something like this will compile:

```
// T is Bar
scala> test((s: String) => Future(Bar(s, None)))
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Bar] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@56f2bbea
```

And using some other type `Baz`, without an instance of `TestBuilder[Baz]` will fail.

```
case class Baz(a: String) extends Foo

scala> test((s: String) => Future(Baz(s)))
<console>:29: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TestBuilder[Baz]
       test((s: String) => Future(Baz(s)))
           ^
```

Comment: great explanation. I take this way.
Thanks alot.

Comment: @Michael_Zajac It seems that `test` method's signature should be `test[T <: Foo : ClassTag]` instead of `test[T <: Foo : ClassTag : TestBuilder]` and needs to have implicit param `(implicit builder: TestBuilder[T])` Could you please update the answer for future reference?

Comment: As is, it _does_ have an implicit parameter (that's what a context bound is), and can be accessed via `implicitly[TestBuilder[T]]`, though it is more convenient to access it by name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do quite what you're looking for. But maybe this would work for you:

```
trait Foo {
  def a: String
  def create(a: String): Foo
}
case class Bar(a: String,b: Option[Int]) extends Foo{
  def create(a: String) = Bar(a,None)
}
case class Buzz(a: String,b: Boolean) extends Foo{
  def create(a: String) = Buzz(a,false)
}
```

You would then have a way to construct a Bar or Buzz without having to specify the second parameter.

BTW, I didn't quite follow your template exactly because I didn't know what *Test* was supposed to be.

Comment: This unfortunately requires you to have an instance of a `Foo` just to create another, where the two aren't really related.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this directly. But one usually constructs case classes through factories -- their companion objects -- and that gives you the flexibility to do what you want in a different way.

Define

```
trait Test {
  def foo : String = ???
}

abstract class Foo[T <: Foo[T]]()(implicit ev : FooMaker[T]) {
  def a: String
}

trait FooMaker[T <: Foo[T]] {
   def apply( test : Test ) : T
}

implicit object Bar extends FooMaker[Bar] {
  def apply(test: Test) = Bar(test.foo,None)
}
case class Bar(a: String,b: Option[Int]) extends Foo[Bar]

implicit object Buzz extends FooMaker[Buzz] {
  def apply(test: Test) = Buzz(test.foo,false)
}
case class Buzz(a: String,b: Boolean) extends Foo[Buzz]
```

But if you try to define a Foo without the factory method in the companion object that you require:

```
case class Barf(a : String, b : Short ) extends Foo[Barf]
```

You'll see

```
scala> case class Barf(a : String, b : Short ) extends Foo[Barf]
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: FooMaker[Barf]
   case class Barf(a : String, b : Short ) extends Foo[Barf]
```

Add the companion object with the factory you need, and it's all good

```
implicit object Barf extends FooMaker[Barf] {
  def apply(test: Test) = Barf(test.foo,0.toShort)
}
case class Barf(a : String, b : Short ) extends Foo[Barf]
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    implicit object Barf extends FooMaker[Barf] {
      def apply(test: Test) = Barf(test.foo,0.toShort)
    }
    case class Barf(a : String, b : Short ) extends Foo[Barf]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Barf
defined class Barf
```

Note that to compile this stuff in the REPL you'll need to use `:paste` because the mutually interdependent definitions can't be defined separately.